# Not throwing compilation error while using NSUInteger for singned integer

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have used NSUInteger and defined a value as -1. This should through compilation error right? But it doesn't.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IRPartAlertType) {
    IRAlertNone,
    IRNoParts,
    IRAllDOAParts,
    IRMoreThanFiveParts,
    IRReviewParts,
    IRSamePartOrderedMoreThanOnce = -1
};
```

But the below code throws error in 3rd value saying that use NSInteger instead of NSUInteger

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IRPartAlertType) {
    IRAlertNone = 0,
    IRNoParts = -1,
    IRAllDOAParts,
    IRMoreThanFiveParts,
    IRReviewParts,
    IRSamePartOrderedMoreThanOnce = -1,
};
```

Any reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-1` is in fact a valid `NSUInteger`, that will be interpreted at compilation time as `4294967295` (the unsigned value of -1, aka `NSUIntegerMax`)

What is not a valid `NSUInteger` is `4294967296` which is, in your failing case, the value of `IRAllDOAParts`, being `IRNoParts+1`, which is how values in an enumeration are set by compiler.
When no explicit value is set, the previous one + 1 is set.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IRPartAlertType) {
    IRAlertNone = 0,
    IRNoParts = -1,    //    > 4294967295
    IRAllDOAParts,     // +1 > 4294967296 > Error
    IRMoreThanFiveParts,
    IRReviewParts,
    IRSamePartOrderedMoreThanOnce = -1, // No +1, no error
};
```

If you look well in Xcode, you will see the error icon is on the line just under = -1, which explains why it doesn't happen when `-1` is the last value.

For example, that will compile:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IRPartAlertType) {
    IRAlertNone = 0,
    IRNoParts = -1,
    IRAllDOAParts = 1, // valid value
    IRMoreThanFiveParts,
    IRReviewParts,
    IRSamePartOrderedMoreThanOnce = -1,
};
```